# Magento 2 - Block in footer doesn't show

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, footer

I'm trying to add a block to a template built from scratch.
Using template-hints I can see that in the footer the following template is rendered

```
app/design/frontend/Merchant/merchant/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer-cms.phtml
```

with some search I fount that the template is configured in `app/design/frontend/Merchant/merchant/Magento_Theme/page_layout/1column.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <!-- REMOVE MAGENTO HEADER & FOOTER -->
    <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.top" remove="true" /> 
    <!-- INCLUDES TYPO3 HEADER & FOOTER -->
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="t3header" as="t3header"
        before="main.content"
        template="Magento_Theme::html/header-cms.phtml"/>
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="t3footer" as="t3footer"
        before="before.body.end"
        template="Magento_Theme::html/footer-cms.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

as I would like to add a newsletter subscription and terms checkbox in the footer, I am trying to do it in `app/code/Myvendor/Newsletter/view/frontend/layout/1column.xml`

but it doesn't show up even after clearing the cache and I can't figure out why

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="t3footer">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="wf.newsletter2" as="wf.newsletter2"
        before="-"
        template="Myvendor_Newsletter::newsletterprivacy.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

I've also tried to put it in the `shop/app/code/Myvendor/Newsletter/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="wf.newsletter" as="wf.newsletter"
            before="-"
            template="Myvendor_Newsletter::newsletterprivacy.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

but nothing happened

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your theme is not virtual

Go to theme table into db, and check type of your theme

[image]after change 1 to 0, flush cache and check it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sunil. I'm sorry but in my 2.1.5 Magento installation I can't find that table

Comment: theme table contain from start of magento 2, please check page 2 of that phpmyadmin.

Comment: actually i'm not using PhpMyAdmin...anyway this is the result of the command `show tables` on the db -->

[link](http://andreaschiffo.it/docs/show_tables)
can you see the themes table?

Comment: seems like lot of table missing please check with core magento2

Answer (score 0):

`t3footer` is a block:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="t3footer" as="t3footer"
        before="before.body.end"
        template="Magento_Theme::html/footer-cms.phtml"/>
```

But you are using `referenceContainer`:

```
<referenceContainer name="t3footer">
  ...
</referenceContainer>
```

So you need to use `referenceBlock`

```
<referenceBlock name="t3footer">
  ...
</referenceBlock>
```

You will need to clear cache if you have it enabled.